# iOS8 - UITableView + Search Bar + custom view for the header

Tags: xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift, ios8

I have `UITableViewController` with `UISearchBarController`.
I'm trying to add a custom view between the table and the search bar like this:
[image]

First of all, in iOS8 (not sure if it the same in previous versions) SearchBar is added as `UITableView's` header and adding additional view to the header removes the SearchBar.

Secondly, it is not possible to add a custom view for the FIRST section using `viewForHeaderInSection` like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section == 0 {
            let view = UIView()
            view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)
            return view
        }
        return nil
    }
```

The code above doesn't produce anything. However, if I return the same view for `section == 1` then I get a view displayed

Does anyone know any solutions for this? I see the only way to solve this by skipping the first section and display all the cells starting from the second section